# what is the output of this "10"+20+30 ? in javascript

Tags: javascript

what will be the output of this when we run this on JavaScript and whats the reason behinds that ? And the concept of this logic ? 10 is a string it is in commas and the other two are digits 20 and 30

Comment: This sounds like an interview question. Did you try running it yourself?

Comment: "102030" ... ...

Comment: + is used for string concatenation and for summing two numbers. Since the 10 is surrounded with double quotation marks, the operation here is concatenating string (10) with another (20 which is casting to string). The result (1020) then concatenated with another string (30 casting to string). The casting from integer to string since the + operation must be done on same type of two operands, which in this case, strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question will be `102030`.In the process of concatenation if a '+' sign is encountered the elements to the right will be contacted as string

```js
console.log("10" + 20 + 30) //102030
console.log(20 + 30 + "10") //5010
console.log(20 + 30 + "10" + 20 + 30) //50102030
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the inbuild snippet runner will not show quotes

Answer (score 1):

`+` is used to both add numbers and concatenate string.

If a string is provided as an operand, the concatenation will take effect over numeric addition.

`+` is evaluated left-to-right. So `"10" + 20 + 30` is the same as `("10" + 20) + 30` which is `"1020" + 30` which will then yeild **`"102030"`**.

Comment: what will the ans ?

Comment: **`"102030"`**.